# Stop/pause node tasks after executing them

Tags: javascript, automation, scripting, bots

If I wait for user input in `node` and depending on it I execute a function and pass some parameters inside it is there any way to stop this function after it starts being executed?
I am creating a `node` app that runs multiple tasks depending on user input and I have no idea how people can "pause" or "stop" some tasks after they start being executed.

I saw some people creating some automation stuff and having stop/pause functionality but how exactly do they achieve it?

Comment: What types of tasks are these and by pause do you mean the task continuosly repeats and the user should be able to stop the repitions?

Comment: I have few methods depending on the user input. User types for example `1 2 2` and for each one I loop and run method number 1 or 2, depending on users input. This methods take some time to run and I would like to be able to stop them if user wants to so for example if user types `stop 1` I would like to stop executing task number 1. Like in automation scripts when you start a task that user specifies and later on allow him to stop it whenever he wants to

Comment: That means canceling 1 completely right?

Comment: @Brother58697 yes exactly

Comment: That's a really interesting question. I tried a few things that didn't really work. If I come back to it and figure it out, I'll post here.

Comment: Also I assume that what you're canceling isn't a repeating loop, but several sequential function calls right?

Comment: @Brother58697 yes

Comment: Figured something out and added it as an answer. I hope this fits your needs.

Answer (score 0):

We can do this by throwing an exception and catching after the main implementation. The app's state after stopping can be set in the catch block.

We can make a function that checks our `stopped` boolean, and throws an exception if it's true. We can then use it as a sort of checkpoint or stopping point throughout our function.

Here's an example:

Note that there are only two checkpoints. i.e. if it starts running `Add(3)` and you stop it, it'll still run `Add(4)`

```js
let stopped = false;
stopButton.onclick = () => stopped = true;

const data = { result: 0 };

function checkpoint() {
  if (stopped) throw new Error();
}

async function add(data, num) {
  console.log(`Adding ${num}`);
  await new Promise((res) => setTimeout(res, 2000));
  data.result += num;
  return data;
}

(async () => {
  try {
    await add(data, 1);
    await add(data, 2);
    checkpoint();
    await add(data, 3);
    await add(data, 4);
    checkpoint();
    await add(data, 5);
    await add(data, 6);
    console.log('Done');
  } catch {
    console.log('Stopped running. Resetting program');
  }
})();
```

```html
<button id="stopButton">Stop</button>
```